# mysql searching row's based on AND

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guy's I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it..

Take a look at this sql table..

[image]

I'm trying to search for a product_id that exists in all filter_cat_id's, so in this example it would be product_id 30, because it exists with filter_cat_id 1 2 and 3.. Product_id 30 exists in the same filter_cat_id twice, otherwise I'd just count the product id's, then the distinct cat id's and make sure the count's match.

Any ideas? Is this possible in mysql? another option would be to use PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your SQL code, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to search for a product_id that exists in all filter_cat_id's, so in this example it would be product_id 30, because it exists with filter_cat_id 1 2 and 3.

In general, this can be done by grouping by product_id and using `HAVING COUNT(product_id) >= x` – where *x* is the number of categories,

```
SELECT product_id FROM table GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) >= 3
```

If you don’t know the number of categories upfront (so that you can insert the actual number into the query), you can get that value with a subquery,

```
SELECT product_id FROM table GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(product_id) >= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) FROM table)
```

---

Edit: OK, so apparently the category_ids to search for come from some kind of search form/filter mechanism.

In that case, the filtering of items has to be added – and the number to compare to must be embedded implicitly, but that should be no problem.

```
SELECT product_id FROM table
  WHERE category_id IN(1,2,3)
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(product_id) >= 3
```

Comment: That's if they use all of the categories though.

Comment: Correct, let me adapt my answer.

Comment: But.. A product id can exist in the same category more than once.  I might have 4 product_id's of 30 that all existed with the same category id. Is their a way to wipe out rows that have the same product_id and category_id?

Comment: _Why_ do you allow multiple values for that, and don’t have a UNIQUE key on that combination?

Comment: Thanks CBroe, but that's pretty much the same answer you gave before. It wont work... Let's say we added 2 product_id's of 20 and gave them a filter_id of 1.. The query will return product id's of 20 and 30

Comment: Can we remove duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    product_id, count(i.product_id) as t
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        tablename
    GROUP BY product_id , filter_cat_id) as i
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING t = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be smart enough to determine the number of distinct categories, and select a product_id that has that number of distinct categories.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT product_id, filter_cat_id
    FROM test.play) a
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(product_id) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT filter_cat_id) FROM test.play)
;
```

Test Data:

[image]

```
Query Result:
30
40
```